# Is $\sin^\alpha(x)$ absolutely continuous on $[0,1]$ for $\alpha\in (0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Prove or disprove:** $f(x)=\sin^{\alpha}x$ is absolutely continuous on $[0,1]$ for all $\alpha\in(0,1)$.

Here is my thought process:

I know that $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[0,1]$ if and only if $f'$ exists a.e. in $[0,1]$, $f'$ is integrable on $[0,1]$, and

$$f(x)-f(0) = \int_a^x f',\quad a\leq x\leq b.\tag{1}$$

Moreover, it is clear that $f'(x) = \alpha(\sin^{\alpha-1}x)(\cos x)$ exists a.e. and is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$, thus Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$. Now

$$\int_0^x \alpha(\sin^{\alpha-1})(\cos x)\,du = \int_0^{\sin x}\alpha u^{\alpha-1}\,du = \sin^{\alpha}x$$ so that $(1)$ holds. Hence $f$ is absolutely continuous.

I haven't really considered that we want $\alpha\in(0,1),$ but I fail to see how this is relevant. Suggestions?

Comment: Why is $f'$ *clearly Riemann* integrable? $f'(x) = \frac{a\cos x}{\sin^{1-\alpha} x} \sim_{x\to 0} \frac{a}{x^{1-\alpha}}$, this does not seem entirely obvious to me.

Comment: Well, fact is that, for instance, $\frac12\cos x\sin^{-\frac12}x$ is integrable on $(0,1)$ (in the sense that $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_\varepsilon^x (\bullet)\,dt$ exists *finite* for all $x\in(0,1)$), but $-\frac12\cos x\sin^{-\frac32}x$ is not.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Is your comment addressed to me? (I know it is Lebesgue-integrable; I am questioning the Riemann-integrability, especially the fact that it "clearly" holds).

Comment: I completely overlooked the fact that $\alpha\in(0,1)$ gives $\sin x$ a negative exponent. I was thinking it was clear since a bounded function is Riemann integrable iff it is continuous a.e., but $f$ is not bounded.

Comment: I reckon this is what makes the question interesting (for $\alpha \geq 1$, $f'$ would be all nice and continuous on $[0,1]$).

Comment: No, @ClementC. , it was for the OP, since he did not know where he was using $\alpha\in(0,1)$

Comment: Why even mention "Riemann"?